# Silex GAE memcache error

Tags: php, google-app-engine, memcached, silex

i tried to setup a Silex project for Google App Engine.
Whenever i call

```
$app->register(new SessionServiceProvider());
```

i get the error:

```
Session Storage was not able to create directory "Memcache"
```

thank you!

Comment: you can't create directory, appengine is sandboxed

Comment: but why directory "Memcache"? GAE should support silex, right?

Comment: why gae should support silex? I think it's the other way around, silex as frameworks is the one who needs to support gae

Comment: maybe this will help you https://github.com/GromNaN/silex-gae